# HTML5 video autoplaying without autoplay attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ios6, mobile-safari, html5-video

I have an embedded HTML5 video that is autoplaying on iOs6.0.1 in mobile Safari without the autoplay attribute being present. Any ideas on what is going on or how to stop the autoplaying?

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I've found that iOS doesn't even support autoplay with the autoplay tag (http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4), but I've never seen it start playing automatically when you don't want it to. Can we have more code?

Comment: Yeah, that's hard to believe since Apple very deliberately disabled autoplay and preload to protect iPhone customer bandwidth. Got a link?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this code: `autoplay="false"`.

Comment: `autoplay="false" preload="none"` according to http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp they're not fully supported...

Comment: I know that this is a very bad approach, but partial support is better than no support. I'll look into some fallbacks and get back to you, but this should be enough to get the code to work on iOS 6.0.1, no problem.

Comment: I am using the code above but I am also using Flash fallback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840792/html5-video-if-files-do-not-exist-revert-to-swf-fall-back/13847548#13847548

Comment: No, as in, HTML fallbacks. If you're using Flash on an iOS device, you're missing the point, as iOS and Flash don't tend to play nice.
You can use `<embed src="../MyVideoSource.mov"/>`, which is compatible with HTML4.01-Transitional and HTML4.01-Strict, as well as XHTML. It's a bit of a useless precaution, as maybe 1-2% of you visitors will have iOS devices without HTML5 support; Apple is a big player in the HTML5 game.

Comment: According to MDN, the presence of the `autoplay` attribute, no matter the value, will cause videos to autoplay. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video